# docker and two services on different ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, package.json

Let's say I want to create two services:

- The first one on port 5000
- The second one on port 7000

So I create docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  project-server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - PORT=5000
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  project-socket-server:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "./Dockerfile-socket"
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    environment:
      - PORT=7000
    depends_on:
      - project-server

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=project_admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=9293
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/data/db
volumes:
  mongo-db:
```

and docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  project-server:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - .:/server
      - /server/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - MONGO_USER=project_admin
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=9293
    command: npm run dev
  project-socket-server:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "./Dockerfile-socket"
      args:
        NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - .:/server
      - /server/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - MONGO_USER=project_admin
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=9293
    command: npm run dev
  mongo:
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=project_admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=9293
```

Dockerfile - for the first service

```
FROM node:15
WORKDIR /server
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=production

ARG NODE_ENV
RUN if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "development" ]; \
        then npm install; \
        else npm install --only=production; \
        fi

COPY . ./
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

And Dockerfile-socket for the second service

```
FROM node:15
WORKDIR /server
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=production

ARG NODE_ENV
RUN if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "development" ]; \
        then npm install; \
        else npm install --only=production; \
        fi

COPY . ./
EXPOSE 7000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

And package.json as well:

```
{
  "name": "project-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js && nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js && nodemon server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@socket.io/mongo-adapter": "^0.2.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.5",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.1",
    "stripe": "^9.11.0",
    "ws": "^8.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16"
  }
}
```

The problem is, after I call docker-compose the both containers will start - there is no problem here, as I call localhost:5000, it gives me correct data, but after I call localhost:7000 I see all the data as if I call localhost:5000. Am I doing something wrong?

**UPD:**

it looks like on port 7000 starts index.js, and not server.js script

index.js file:

```
const port = process.env.PORT;
console.log("connected to port index " + port);
```

gives back:

```
connected to port index 5000
```

server.js file:

```
const port = process.env.PORT;
console.log("connected to port server " + port);
```

gives back:

```
connected to port index 7000
```

**UPD2:**

inspect port 5000:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "6a7729ba9734df523fc7424221d866a63a83faec716f6c7efbf77a3797ff9a51",
        "Created": "2022-07-10T16:01:57.4280865Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "npm",
            "run",
            "dev"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 29648,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-07-10T16:01:58.2066126Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:797d9993a50984ae392476eb54bf79014011d6f146c6b9f2b2f4d46bb6ecdf20",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/6a7729ba9734df523fc7424221d866a63a83faec716f6c7efbf77a3797ff9a51/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/6a7729ba9734df523fc7424221d866a63a83faec716f6c7efbf77a3797ff9a51/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/6a7729ba9734df523fc7424221d866a63a83faec716f6c7efbf77a3797ff9a51/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/6a7729ba9734df523fc7424221d866a63a83faec716f6c7efbf77a3797ff9a51/6a7729ba9734df523fc7424221d866a63a83faec716f6c7efbf77a3797ff9a51-json.log",
        "Name": "/project-server_project-server_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/Users/nikita/Desktop/project-server:/server:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "project-server_default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "5000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cb1f731b1d50d3ecb220dd8769e1e9088d501429a7760b23474b40fb2baae477-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/z2db8ueu6gzx4g6kml9gm4lqh/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4a5siyd2j04hfi7shvk5uyen8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/je4ef30hthjwlgjf41mrz7c6p/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/o1n9ak157b8zru8l8zip2oiwu/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dbdi66mhdlurq8ljn2p8gnotx/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/30480c3ac46a01c8279f265b8055162c1c628ed901b2fa5f13a481933fb6acf2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/18eb589f35db055e79336c54cc0e5da75d5fed390e4ef3edc149767578e4d304/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1f82814e597da8a6eef3b98677f9a00eda7ca517b3413fcc43de663692a522b2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/68e13aa159454b660beda0b20784243a29422d1e67c76a4043d485d2f2bf7fc2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3befd14aea9bb18d7ba0fd5aecc2205420fc373fa70b99d93ce1c85de6434fc0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/85a4d0b611d3d1cd423a78a68cdede7193f8665fef0cfdf573e849abdf32aa08/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3ee2ce61fd86f7d3eee34d744dfc313068ed76c3a1df068db9d3614c1c4626d5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/785dcc56e0a473c70c3a8b19b2a163c729fe43c8a2cf8f1a17afc30af0b6a81c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a3d6650199856fc04ea61fb1936888adc9324b19fd8ec60f19445bc2fafed8ac/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cb1f731b1d50d3ecb220dd8769e1e9088d501429a7760b23474b40fb2baae477/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cb1f731b1d50d3ecb220dd8769e1e9088d501429a7760b23474b40fb2baae477/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cb1f731b1d50d3ecb220dd8769e1e9088d501429a7760b23474b40fb2baae477/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/nikita/Desktop/project-server",
                "Destination": "/server",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "54ae173b93a965d9ac3feba255694b31718c684026fb05fc5d811de873319ebf",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/54ae173b93a965d9ac3feba255694b31718c684026fb05fc5d811de873319ebf/_data",
                "Destination": "/server/node_modules",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "6a7729ba9734",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5000/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PORT=5000",
                "NODE_ENV=development",
                "MONGO_USER=project_admin",
                "MONGO_PASSWORD=9293",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NODE_VERSION=15.14.0",
                "YARN_VERSION=1.22.5"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "npm",
                "run",
                "dev"
            ],
            "Image": "project-server_project-server",
            "Volumes": {
                "/server": {},
                "/server/node_modules": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/server",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "3ac7f110d763362d49938c1ed5213e7e50072c8ab95ee0b8c58f9dc2826d9ae6",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "project-server",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "docker-compose.yml,docker-compose.dev.yml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/Users/nikita/Desktop/project-server",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "project-server",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "ebc830dec3ca4c02819e90f2fa79b0db8f88043ba56abb67795bb510fba14ad4",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/ebc830dec3ca",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "project-server_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "project-server",
                        "6a7729ba9734"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "3f5807c2c3187687876240b47feb4fd5e997c561dbef6462fd3a195ad0b11f43",
                    "EndpointID": "2ccabd2ce6680746c69b9dfd03b85cf17fe9fea4d614ffc58e2e4b74e1eec9a5",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.192.1",
                    "IPAddress": "192.168.192.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 20,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:c0:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

inspect port 7000

```
[
    {
        "Id": "856312d4b656a689e54567e0c2f33319d7396e16c2d0927b003c4a204b6d58b4",
        "Created": "2022-07-10T16:01:58.2531359Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "npm",
            "run",
            "dev"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 29787,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-07-10T16:01:58.6972426Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:d9831965ad489f691c2dedbdd5c12c4afc780322e43105add43f0db791d88362",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/856312d4b656a689e54567e0c2f33319d7396e16c2d0927b003c4a204b6d58b4/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/856312d4b656a689e54567e0c2f33319d7396e16c2d0927b003c4a204b6d58b4/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/856312d4b656a689e54567e0c2f33319d7396e16c2d0927b003c4a204b6d58b4/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/856312d4b656a689e54567e0c2f33319d7396e16c2d0927b003c4a204b6d58b4/856312d4b656a689e54567e0c2f33319d7396e16c2d0927b003c4a204b6d58b4-json.log",
        "Name": "/project-server_project-socket-server_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/Users/nikita/Desktop/project-server:/socket-server:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "project-server_default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "7000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "7000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f92796078a9effb55efa307514fcaea257d3ca5cfe1fa9717dd8f26eda800a8b-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/z2db8ueu6gzx4g6kml9gm4lqh/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4a5siyd2j04hfi7shvk5uyen8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/je4ef30hthjwlgjf41mrz7c6p/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/o1n9ak157b8zru8l8zip2oiwu/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dbdi66mhdlurq8ljn2p8gnotx/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/30480c3ac46a01c8279f265b8055162c1c628ed901b2fa5f13a481933fb6acf2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/18eb589f35db055e79336c54cc0e5da75d5fed390e4ef3edc149767578e4d304/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1f82814e597da8a6eef3b98677f9a00eda7ca517b3413fcc43de663692a522b2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/68e13aa159454b660beda0b20784243a29422d1e67c76a4043d485d2f2bf7fc2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3befd14aea9bb18d7ba0fd5aecc2205420fc373fa70b99d93ce1c85de6434fc0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/85a4d0b611d3d1cd423a78a68cdede7193f8665fef0cfdf573e849abdf32aa08/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3ee2ce61fd86f7d3eee34d744dfc313068ed76c3a1df068db9d3614c1c4626d5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/785dcc56e0a473c70c3a8b19b2a163c729fe43c8a2cf8f1a17afc30af0b6a81c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a3d6650199856fc04ea61fb1936888adc9324b19fd8ec60f19445bc2fafed8ac/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f92796078a9effb55efa307514fcaea257d3ca5cfe1fa9717dd8f26eda800a8b/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f92796078a9effb55efa307514fcaea257d3ca5cfe1fa9717dd8f26eda800a8b/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f92796078a9effb55efa307514fcaea257d3ca5cfe1fa9717dd8f26eda800a8b/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/nikita/Desktop/project-server",
                "Destination": "/socket-server",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "7a7d8d6a4c7c004640e16bc4f50be2f9b2cfb94855ebbf864999d5f8a263aa54",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/7a7d8d6a4c7c004640e16bc4f50be2f9b2cfb94855ebbf864999d5f8a263aa54/_data",
                "Destination": "/socket-server/node_modules",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "856312d4b656",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "7000/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PORT=7000",
                "NODE_ENV=development",
                "MONGO_USER=project_admin",
                "MONGO_PASSWORD=9293",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NODE_VERSION=15.14.0",
                "YARN_VERSION=1.22.5"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "npm",
                "run",
                "dev"
            ],
            "Image": "project-server_project-socket-server",
            "Volumes": {
                "/socket-server": {},
                "/socket-server/node_modules": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/server",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "1b0d7e398115bad6eae26e92b1d54d15163ca74e7f6570492daf14f023014052",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "project-server",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "docker-compose.yml,docker-compose.dev.yml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/Users/nikita/Desktop/project-server",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "project-socket-server",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "fe3cffcd72a06aaa92c87cd94280ce914bc13f7e269c51a98901ce639ba4a4d1",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "7000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "7000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/fe3cffcd72a0",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "project-server_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "project-socket-server",
                        "856312d4b656"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "3f5807c2c3187687876240b47feb4fd5e997c561dbef6462fd3a195ad0b11f43",
                    "EndpointID": "bd3915089cf996887646b20d34386214eca5ea484daa74284c5e1a63c144c3bd",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.192.1",
                    "IPAddress": "192.168.192.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 20,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:c0:04",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: It looks like you have `volumes:` that overwrite both containers' code with the same host `./server` directory.  You should delete those `volumes:` blocks so that you run the code that's built into the images; since you `build:` images from two different trees you should get different results.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried to remove those blocks, to change the path, but it didn't work out - same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docker containers `inspect` output you provided it seems you are running the following command:

```
 "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
 "Args": [
   "npm",
   "run",
   "dev"
 ],

 

 "Cmd": [
   "npm",
   "run",
   "dev"
 ]
```

in both of them, which is consistent with the `command` you provided for both containers in your `docker-compose.dev.yml` file:

```
command: npm run dev
```

As stated in the docker-compose [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command), please, be aware that by doing so you are overwriting your containers `Dockerfile` command.

It means that both containers are running the `dev` scripts.

According to your project structure it turns out both containers are sharing the same `package.json` and code.

In `package.json` you defined the `dev` script like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon index.js && nodemon server.js",
  "dev": "nodemon index.js && nodemon server.js"
},
```

It means you are launching in both containers `index.js`, with different ports, according to your `PORT` variables declaration in each container, but they are both running `index.js` after all.

That explains why you are getting the same output in every call:

```
connected to port index ...
```

Although my advice is that you separate the source code for every container, to solve the problem you could try running a different script per every container. I mean, in your `package.json` file I would include a new script, `server`, for example:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon index.js && nodemon server.js",
  "dev": "nodemon index.js",
  "server": "nodemon server.js"
},
```

And use the new script when launching your container in docker-compose:

```yaml
  project-socket-server:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "./Dockerfile-socket"
      args:
        NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - .:/server
      - /server/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - MONGO_USER=project_admin
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=9293
    command: npm run server
```

As an alternative, you can remove the lines:

```
command: npm run dev
```

from your `docker-compose.dev.yml` file:

```yaml
ersion: "3"
services:
  project-server:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - .:/server
      - /server/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - MONGO_USER=project_admin
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=9293
  project-socket-server:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "./Dockerfile-socket"
      args:
        NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - .:/server
      - /server/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - MONGO_USER=project_admin
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=9293
  mongo:
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=project_admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=9293
```

This will make docker to use the `CMD` provided in the different `Dockerfile`s:

```
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

and:

```
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

which I think it will work as well.

As I said, please, consider in any case reorder your project structure to avoid using the same directory for building your two apps, as you can see it could be the cause of several problems.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in "[Putting Your NodeJS App in a Docker Container](https://www.thisdot.co/blog/putting-your-nodejs-app-in-a-docker-container)"

> `EXPOSE` is a little different from the other instructions in that it doesn't have a practical purpose.
> It only exists to provide metadata about what port the container expects to expose.
>
> You don't need to use EXPOSE in your container, but anyone who has to understand how to connect to it will appreciate it.

You need to check if `CMD ["node", "server.js"]` in `Dockerfile-socket` does take advantage *at runtime* of the `project-socket-server` service `environment: PORT=7000`.
It uses the [`socketio/socket.io-mongo-adapter`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-mongo-adapter), which could use the port of the existing MongoDB it adapts to.

---

As [discussed with the OP](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246324/discussion-between-vonc-and-igentlich), and detailed [jccampanero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13942448/jccampanero)'s more accurate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72932378/6309), the root cause is the common `package.json`, with the common dev directive starting both `index.js` (first) and then `server.js`.

The first (`index.js`) would answer the query even though it is in the server container.

Comment: I made an update

Comment: @IGentlich Can you docker inspect the two running containers, to check their port mapping?

Comment: sure, made another update

Comment: @IGentlich Considering the schema in https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-mongo-adapter, is it possible that you seeing the same data on localhost:7000 (same as localhost:5000) is the result of the mongo-adapter doing its job, and broadcasting packets between multiple Socket.IO servers? In other words, what would you consider as the expected result?

Comment: I don't use mongo adapter right now, index.js and server.js scripts contain only console.log line. 

What I expect as result:
index.js returns "connected to port index 5000",
server.js returns "connected to port server 7000".

What I get right now:
index.js returns "connected to port index 5000",
server.js returns "connected to port index 7000".

Comment: @IGentlich OK so `port index` instead of `port server`. Any chance you could `docker exec -it <yourServerContainer> bash`, and check the content of the `server.js`?

Comment: Sure, `docker exec -it project-server_project-socket-server_1 bash` gives `console.log("connected to port server " + port);` back - as it should be

Comment: I mean `cat server.js` inside the `project-server_project-socket-server_1` container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246324/discussion-between-vonc-and-igentlich).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @VonC. I have never based my answers in other people's ones without the proper attribution, and I will never do: this is in fact one of the things I fight against here in SO. I posted my answer based exclusively on the contents of the OP question, it contains all the necessary information to do it. Any way, sorry mate, I read your comments and discussion to a full extend and I realized that you effectively mention that probably `index.js` is being called in both containers. If you consider appropriate, I will remove the answer with glad. But please, consider reviewing

Comment: your answer to include a better description of the problem: I think it could be valuable for others to understand what is going on. In addition, your current answer only mentions `EXPOSE`, and the OP never mentions it in the question and is not the problem. You mentioned as well the socker.io mongo adapter, and neither is of relevance here. As I told, I will remove the answer if you want to, because in the end the effort of helping the OP in your discussion is worth value but please, consider review your own one: you are welcome to take the information from mine if you consider it appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much @VonC, I upvoted your answer as well. In any way, mate, honestly, if you want to because you consider I copied something, I will remove my answer and, I am aware you don't need to, but you are very welcome to use any of its contents if you want to improve your own one. The only important thing is help the OP and other people in the future when they come across the information.

Comment: @jccampanero "The only important thing is helping the OP and other people in the future when they come across the information.". My thoughts exactly. I see your answer was selected, and I agree: it is a good one.